# TMTumblrSDK: No visible @interface ... declares selector "handleOpenURL"

Tags: objective-c, xcode6.3, tmtumblrsdk

I have no idea why, but using Xcode 6.2 this compiled fine; now it doesn't in Xcode 6.3, failing with:

```
TMTumblrSDK: No visible @interface ... declares selector "handleOpenURL"
```

Looking at the header file and it clearly shows that method is there.

```
#import "TMAPIClient.h"
// ...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    [[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I tried a clean, deleting derived data, and I even tried with `<TMTumblrSDK/TMAPIClient.h>` but no dice? 
Via CocoaPods, I'm `Using TMTumblrSDK (2.1.1)`

Comment: You need to remove the #ifDef part in the file, and then you can use that method.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this has been removed by design, per [this commit](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK/commit/c4fb542710d4d7d931e390c3755784ee4f151cf3):

> Unfortunately, [Apple has started rejecting
>   apps](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK/issues/67#issuecomment-59384303)
>   that use three-legged OAuth via Safari, the preferred way to retrieve
>   access tokens from a security perspective. For  the time being, please
>   either:
>
> - [Request xAuth access](http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps)
> - Use a web view inside of your application (here's [a TMTumblrSDK fork](https://github.com/felixmo/TMTumblrSDK/)  that adds this
>     capability, we may add it to the SDK proper at a later date)
>
> We hope to have more to share on this note shortly.

Comment: does anybody have a solution for this. i tried to request xauth, but the say: "Unfortunately, we tend to reserve xauth for when a trusted app is ready for mass distribution. You should still be able to use oauth to kick users out to a browser and back to your app" and when i told tumblr support that we had oauth but it does not work, they said "Unfortunately, this is a little beyond me. Thankfully, we’ve also created a Google Group where application developers and Tumblr engineers respond to API-related questions, so check it out to see if someone has already answered your question"

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly, but OAuth using a browser to authenticate is the correct solution.

Comment: so we are using TMTumblrSDK 1.1.1 for an iOS app. and it works using oauth. if i try to update to 2.2.0 (the last version) i get the error mentioned in the post. The doc says to either use xauth or display a webview inside the app. Tumblr support would not give us xauth, so we have to use oauth - which cannot be used because it has been removed in 2.2.0.

Comment: Look at the fork mentioned in my answer

Comment: Hi, I get Error posting to Tumblr Error Domain=Request failed Code=404 "(null)" when I try to post the photo.